# Adding standard metadata to a table - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, metadata

I worked with the ESRI geodb where you can insert (into the "property" of a table) some metadata (also compliant to some International standard), like creation date,  organization, source, copyright info etc.

Is there something similar in Postgres, for metadata of a table as a whole? I know only `COMMENT` but it seems too poor for my purposes.

Comment: Those table properties I suppose were just rows in some other table, that you were populating over some form. If so - yes you can do that in any db

Comment: Thanks!... But, how can I connect the "metadata table" to the entire "data table"? Because I am only able to create a relationship that links the records of one table to the records of the other... :-( while I'd like to connect the "metadata table" (as a whole) to the "data table" as a whole... I don't think this is feasible, or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same wave. I posted an example of how you can save "metadata" and how +- I think it was done in ESRI geodb

Comment: I think you are referring to Dublin Core? You could stash Dublin Core JSON or XML in a COMMENT, but I'd just use another table with `table_schema` and `table_name` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a very naive example of how you can save your wanted "metadata"**

lest assume you have two tables you want to have data about:

```
t=# create table so66(i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 5.431 ms
t=# create table so67(i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 4.797 ms
```

and a "metadata" holder table:

```
t=# create table metadata(tname text, created timestamptz, details json);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 6.814 ms
t=# insert into metadata select 'so66',now(),'{"organization":"n/a","source":"manual","catalog":false}';
INSERT 0 1
Time: 3.144 ms
t=# insert into metadata select 'so76',now(),'{"organization":"home","source":"manual","catalog":true}';
INSERT 0 1
Time: 0.907 ms

t=# select * from metadata ;
 tname |            created            |                         details
-------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 so66  | 2017-04-21 09:24:08.233346+00 | {"organization":"n/a","source":"manual","catalog":false}
 so76  | 2017-04-21 09:24:26.641526+00 | {"organization":"home","source":"manual","catalog":true}
(2 rows)

Time: 0.253 ms
```

I used json to save arbitrary details. Of course you can add columns with special data types for your needs. Also you might want to use oids instead of table names or do some logic on insert/update of it.

Comment: Now I got! You simply put the table names in a field! :-o it was so easy, I didn't think... Thanks a lot! This really helped me!